# Should I commit Pulumi stack files to git?

Tags: pulumi

I'm starting the process of re-implementing our infrastructure-as-code with Pulumi and I'm seeing the different stack configuration files (dev/test etc) in my git project. The stack config files include encryption salts however, is it safe to commit these to Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it is. From the docs:

> Decrypting this ciphertext requires the encryption key that was used
> to create it. For stacks managed with Pulumi Cloud, these keys are
> obtained automatically, but only for users with read access to the
> stack. For self-managed backends, the keys must be supplied by the
> user, either by providing the stack’s current passphrase (when using
> the `passphrase` provider) or by authenticating with the stack’s
> encryption provider.
>
> It’s therefore considered safe, and good practice, to check these
> files into source control, as doing so allows you to version your code
> and configuration in tandem. If you’d prefer not to check in these
> files, however, you can easily rebuild them, using the most recently
> deployed configuration, with `pulumi config refresh`.

The thing you need to keep secret is the passphrase itself. The salt has no use without that.

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/secrets/#committing-configuration-to-source-control